# Three variables on conditional tags

Tags: conditional-tags

I'm trying to return $ad_code if three variables are present, but it doesn't allow the third variable I'm trying to add. I want to exclude a category.

I am trying to use (in accordance with WordPress' ["conditional tags"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags))

```
if ( is_single() && ! is_category( '1293' ) && ! is_admin() )  {
    return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
}

return $content;
```

The code (including the code that specifies what $ad_code is) works. Just when I try to add in `&& ! is_category( '1293' )` it still displays on all posts (not just 1293). I tried using the category name as well, but that also did the same thing.

The third variables I've tried either stop `$ad_code` from loading on all or on no posts.

Comment: What about `! is_category( 1293 )` (without single quotes)

Comment: Unfortunately, just the same. It still shows on all posts.

Comment: `! is_category( 1293 )` checks for any post that is _not_ in category 1293. Is that not what you want?

Comment: From the codex, ! means they DON'T put those posts. IE it should display all posts but NOT 1293. This is what I'm trying to make happen.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks for the heads up Pieter Goosen. I do know that a few of them actually haven't been answered yet, but I'll go recheck them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional, `is_category()` is wrong here. `is_category()` checks whether or not you are actually on a category page. By using the `!` operator in conjuction with `is_category()` and ID `1293`, this part of the condition will always return true except when you are actually on the category page for category `1293`.

If you need to exclude a certain set of posts from the category `1293`, you should use the conditional check, `in_category()` or `has_category()` (*in essence, they both are excatly the same*). So your conditional statement should look something like this:

```
if (    is_single() // Make sure we are on a single page
     && ! in_category( '1293' ) // Make sure the post does not belong to category 1293
     && ! is_admin() // Make sure this is not an admin page
)  {
    return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
}
```

Comment: Good one, and thank you for your help! That worked and it explained the difference as well. Wish I had enough points to upvote it, but it's checked.

Comment: No problem. At least you also gain 2 reputation points for accepting answers, so you will get there :-). Enjoy